# Google Sheets - conditional format background using text string with a hex color

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In Google Sheets, is it possible to make the background color in cell B40 equal to the hex value saved in B39? We want the background color to link to cell B39 specifically because we want to be able to change B39's hex value in order to then change the other cells background color.

This doesn't seem possible, but perhaps we are missing something.

Answer (score 1):

you can use addon Team Color:

**https://www.crx4chrome.com/add-ons/ldggbboahhbelionpagpifdnkicagagg/**

[image]

Comment: It seems like the link to the chrome web store to get this addon is not working. What is best way to install?

Comment: @Canovice yes, hence chrome webstore link not provided. see: https://www.reddit.com/r/SideProject/comments/3aljoc/team_color_a_google_sheet_addon_rejected_for_4/

Comment: the Team Color - Google Sheets add-on link in this reddit link doesn't seem to work either?

Comment: @Canovice you should be able to install it manually - https://www.cnet.com/tech/services-and-software/how-to-install-chrome-extensions-manually/

Comment: mmm still struggling, seems like this is the only option though, this functionality not build into sheets